# How to set RocksDBStateBackend parameter in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I use the follow code to set RocksDBStateBackend and it option, it can run correctly locally, but can't be submitted to cluster.

```
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    RocksDBStateBackend rocksDBBackEnd = new RocksDBStateBackend("file:///Users/zsh/tmp/rocksdb");
    rocksDBBackEnd.setOptions(new OptionsFactory() {
        @Override
        public DBOptions createDBOptions(DBOptions currentOptions) {
            return currentOptions;
        }

        @Override
        public ColumnFamilyOptions createColumnOptions(ColumnFamilyOptions currentOptions) {

            final long blockCacheSize = 8 * 1024 * 1024;
            final long blockSize = 4 * 1024;
            final long targetFileSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
            final long writeBufferSize = 64 * 1024 * 1024;
            final int writeBufferNum = 1; //default 2
            final int minBufferToMerge = 1; //default 2

            return currentOptions
                    .setCompactionStyle(CompactionStyle.LEVEL)
                    .setTargetFileSizeBase(targetFileSize)
                    .setWriteBufferSize(writeBufferSize)
                    .setMaxWriteBufferNumber(writeBufferNum)
                    .setMinWriteBufferNumberToMerge(minBufferToMerge)
                    .setTableFormatConfig(
                            new BlockBasedTableConfig()
                                    .setBlockCacheSize(blockCacheSize)
                                    .setBlockSize(blockSize)
                    );

        }
    });
    env.setStateBackend(rocksDBBackEnd);
    ....
    env.execute();
```

When i submit my job this way:

```
flink run -d -c gerryzhou.metricTest target/gerryzhou.flink-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

it throw below exception:

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: JobManager did not respond within 60000 milliseconds
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.runDetached(ClusterClient.java:505)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient.submitJob(StandaloneClusterClient.java:103)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:442)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.DetachedEnvironment.finalizeExecute(DetachedEnvironment.java:76)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:387)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:838)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:259)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1086)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1133)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1130)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1129)
```

And the jobmanager.log look like this

```
        2017-06-29 15:37:16,651 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                      - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@10.242.98.255:51891] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [gerryzhou.metricTest$1]
    2017-06-29 15:37:16,651 ERROR Remoting                                                      - gerryzhou.metricTest$1
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gerryzhou.metricTest$1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:677)
```

I have changed my code and implemented the `OptionsFactory` with a single class file `MRocksDBFactory`, use it like this `rocksDBBackEnd.setOptions(new MRocksDBFactory());`. The error info in jobManager.log become this:

```
2017-06-29 16:29:27,162 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@10.242.98.255:52638] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [gerryzhou.MRocksDBFactory]
2017-06-29 16:29:27,163 ERROR Remoting                                                      - gerryzhou.MRocksDBFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gerryzhou.MRocksDBFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:677)
    at akka.util.ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.scala:19)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1819)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1986)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$1.apply(Serializer.scala:136)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer.fromBinary(Serializer.scala:136)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(Serialization.scala:104)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:98)
    at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.deserialize(MessageSerializer.scala:23)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$lzycompute$1(Endpoint.scala:58)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$1(Endpoint.scala:58)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.dispatch(Endpoint.scala:76)
    at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:967)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
    at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:437)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, but maybe https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html will help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it doesn't seem to solve my problem, it seem to be a serializer problem. I have change my code and implement the OptionsFactory interface in class `MRocksDBFactory`. The jobmanager.log's info become `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gerryzhou.MRocksDBFactory`.

Comment: Finally, this is a bug for reporting to flink, here is the issue link [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7041](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7041).